# Is there a email service that has an API for parses new email messages?

Tags: php, javascript, api, email

I'm looking for a way to use Javascript/PHP to automatically check an email account for a new email message. If there is one, then I want it to open it, grab the message contents, and display those contents on the webpage that my visitor is viewing.

Is this possible? What email services provide this functionality. It doesn't have to be gmail or hotmail, it can be any email address. As long as there is an API that can do this.

Only 1 email message will need to be grabbed and only one will be stored.

Answer (score 2):

Every e-mail service will come with their own API which you will have to use. more or less all email services give you this functionality. I dont think that there is a generic API for all email services, if you need google mail, you need the google API,extracting yahoo mail will require the yahoo API. 
 For gmail we have https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/ and 
 for Yahoo we have http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/ 
 You can search for more details regarding the license of these API's online.